# Convert date from YYYYMMDD to DD/MM/YYYY format in PHP

Tags: php, date

I've a MySQL database table in which the date is stored in YYYYMMDD format. Eg: 20121226.

I want to display this date in DD/MM/YYYY format. Eg: 26/12/2012

What I came up with is to use `substr` to extract the day, month and year separately.
I would like to know if there's an easier way to do this.

Also, is there a way to convert this date to "26 December 2012" format without the need to write separate code?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can easily use the DateTime class to do this

```
$retrieved = '20121226';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', $retrieved);
echo $date->format('d/m/Y');
```

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Answer (score 3):

In your SQL statement you can format the date differently.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date_column, '%d/%m/%Y') AS my_date FROM my_table
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution :

`SELECT DATE_FORMAT('20121226', '%d/%m/%Y');`

=>

```
DATE_FORMAT('20121226', '%d/%m/%Y')
26/12/2012
```

OR

`SELECT DATE_FORMAT('20121226', '%W %M %Y');`

=>

```
DATE_FORMAT('20121226', '%W %M %Y')
Wednesday December 2012
```

Check this for more formatting:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format